# Can we isolate a user from the mod_authz authentication?

Tags: apache, svn, authentication

Can we isolate a subversion user using the `mod_authz` authentication such that they will only be authenticated to a single subversion repository? Right now we are hosting multiple repositories via apache, and our access_file is global across all repositories. This means if we use the `*=r` option, then *all* users will have read access. We would like to introduce a user into that environment so they will only have access to a single repo, and they will not be included in other repository access via the `*=r` option. Is this type of configuration available?

Thanks, 
Suresh

Comment: Would other tags be also appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **NOT** modifier on global scope of the authz file:

```
[/]
*=
~single_repo_user=r

[single_repo:/]
*=
single_repo_user=r
```

This reads:

for all repositories, nobody has any permission, except he is **not** user named single_repo_user, than user has read permission
for repository "single_repo" nobody has access except single_repo_user who has read access

So only single_user_repo has no permission. everybody else has read permission.

You can of course just delete the user name out of the htpasswd  file..

See more infos here:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz

Comment: Peter, thank you so much for your reply. Could not reply back immediately i apologize for that.Anyhow thank you once again for your reply.